# Converting a named list to a data.fame cleanly (where the names are dates)

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm new to R and trying to make a data frame out of a named list:

```
> z <- list(2,4)
> names(z) <- c("2010-01-01", "2010-01-02")
> z
$`2010-01-01`
[1] 2

$`2010-01-02`
[1] 4
```

i.e. the result should be the same as what this produces:

```
> data.frame(dates=as.Date(c("2010-01-01", "2010-01-02")), val=c(2,4))
       dates val
1 2010-01-01   2
2 2010-01-02   4
```

How would you do this cleanly in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> data.frame(dates=as.Date(names(z)),val=unlist(z),row.names=NULL)
       dates val
1 2010-01-01   2
2 2010-01-02   4
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach using R base functions

```
> x <- do.call(rbind, z)
> data.frame(dates=as.Date(rownames(x)), val=x[,1], row.names=NULL)
       dates val
1 2010-01-01   2
2 2010-01-02   4
```

Using `ldply` from plyr

```
> library(plyr)
> y <- ldply(z)
> transform(y, date=as.Date(.id), val=V1)[,-c(1,2)]
        date val
1 2010-01-01   2
2 2010-01-02   4
```

Comment: you need an `as.Date()` somewhere if you're going to get the format exactly right ...

Comment: yes, good catch, didnt see the format for dates in the question, will updated that point.

Comment: That's interesting. What are the relative merits of doing it this way vs. mrip's more compact suggestion - would it be faster if working on a large dataset?